# Oracle Case clause can not evaluate an "AND" with tow or more expressions

Tags: oracle, case

Oracle behaves really extrange with the next query:

I am trying to evaluate these three records, one of them should show the column `digitado = 1` because it accomplishes all the conditions, which are, `NUM_DOCUMENTO_ENCABEZADO iS NOT NULL and ORIGEN_PLANILLA = 2`

```
NUM_DOCUMENTO   NUM_DOCUMENTO_ENCABEZADO    ORIGEN_PLANILLA
8220568059                8220568059                    2
8220681644                                              2
940723593097                                        1


select  x.num_documento,
        x.origen_planilla,
        x.num_documento_encabezado,
        case    
                when  x.num_documento_encabezado > '0' and x.origen_planilla = 2  then 
                    1 
                else 
                    0
        end digitado
from    (
            select  h.num_documento,
                    h.num_documento_encabezado,
                    h.origen_planilla
            from    (
                        select  a.num_documento,
                                c.num_documento num_documento_encabezado,
                                case when NVl(UPPER(a.txt_observacion),'X') like '%SGP%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END origen_planilla
                        from    epsis.ryc_recaudo               a,
                                epsis.ryc_recaudo_unificado     b,
                                epsis.ryc_documento_encabezado  c
                        where a.fec_pago            >=  to_date('28082013','ddmmyyyy') ---aca se coloca el dia del ultimo proceso,
                        and     a.fec_pago          <   to_date('25092013','ddmmyyyy')-- el cecaudo viene un dia atrasados
                        and     b.num_documento(+)  =   a.num_documento
                        and     c.num_documento(+)  =   b.num_documento --80595
                        and     a.num_documento     in  ( '940723593097', '8220681644','8220568059')
                    ) h,
                    epsis.ryc_divide_documento f,
                    epsis.ryc_documento_encabezado g
            where   f.num_documento(+) = h.num_documento
            and     g.num_documento(+) =f.num_division
            group by  h.num_documento,
                    h.num_documento_encabezado,
                    h.origen_planilla
        ) x
```

This is the result:

```
NUM_DOCUMENTO   ORIGEN_PLANILLA NUM_DOCUMENTO_ENCABEZADO    DIGITADO
8220568059                 2           8220568059               0
8220681644                 2                                    0
940723593097           1                                    0
```

The column `DIGITADO` should be "1" for the first record.

Oracle can not evaluate this "CASE" properly:

```
case    
    when  x.num_documento_encabezado > '0' and x.origen_planilla = 2  then 
          1 
    else 
          0
end digitado
```

I have tried diferent things, for example if I change the previous code for this:

```
case    
    when  length(x.num_documento_encabezado||x.origen_planilla) > 1  then 
          1 
    else 
          0
end digitado
```

This is the result:

```
NUM_DOCUMENTO   ORIGEN_PLANILLA NUM_DOCUMENTO_ENCABEZADO    DIGITADO
8220568059                 2            8220568059              1
8220681644                 2                                    0
940723593097           1                                    0
```

It works for every record, but that is not the point, the point is that oracle is not able to evaluate the "AND" expression, and the ortiginal query is much longer than the example displayed.

Now, another extrange this is that, when I execute the query only for the record that is ok, I mean this

```
and     a.num_documento     in  ('8220568059')
```

the "AND" expression in the case sentence works properly with the original "CASE".

Result:

```
NUM_DOCUMENTO   ORIGEN_PLANILLA NUM_DOCUMENTO_ENCABEZADO    DIGITADO
8220568059                 2             8220568059             1
```

Another thing is that, and here is where i believe the problem is, when no outer join in the second subquery, then the query runs ok, but I need that outer join, I am talking about this:

```
where   f.num_documento(+) = h.num_documento
and     g.num_documento(+) =f.num_division
```

I really don't want to rewrite the full query, does anyone know why this happen?

---

Create and insert statements, these ones reproduce the issue

```
create table tmp_origin
(
    doc varchar2(30),
    val number,
    obs varchar2(30)
);

create table tmp_uni
(
    doc varchar2(30),
    doc_origin varchar2(30)
);

create table tmp_div
(
    doc varchar2(30),
    doc_div  varchar2(30)
);

insert into tmp_origin values ('8220568059',100000, 'NORMAL');

insert into tmp_origin values ('8220681644',200000, 'NORMAL');

insert into tmp_origin values ('940723593097',300000, 'SGP');

commit;

insert into tmp_uni values ('8220568059','8220568059');

commit;
```

This is the query adapted to the above lines, I have also added some others cases, so you can compare and identify that the first one is not working

```
select  x.num_documento,
        x.origen_planilla,
        x.num_documento_encabezado,
        case    
                when  x.num_documento_encabezado  is not null and x.origen_planilla = 2  then 
                    1 
                else 
                    0
        end digitado,
        case    
                when  length(x.num_documento_encabezado||x.origen_planilla) > 1  then 
                    1 
                else 
                    0
        end digitado2,
        case    
                when  x.origen_planilla = 2 then
                    case 
                        when x.num_documento_encabezado  is not null then 
                            1 
                        else 
                            0
                    end 
                else 
                    0
        end digitado3
from    (
            select  h.num_documento,
                    h.num_documento_encabezado,
                    h.origen_planilla
            from    (
                        select  a.doc num_documento,
                                b.doc num_documento_encabezado,
                                case when NVl(UPPER(a.obs),'X') like '%SGP%' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END origen_planilla
                        from    tmp_origin               a,
                                tmp_uni     b
                        where   a.doc     in  ( '940723593097', '8220681644','8220568059')
                        and     b.doc(+)  =   a.doc
                    ) h,
                    tmp_div f
            where   f.doc(+) = h.num_documento
            group by  h.num_documento,
                    h.num_documento_encabezado,
                    h.origen_planilla
        ) x
```

Comment: Using the values you imply the inner query returns, you [seem to get the expected results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/17830). Comparing the string representation of the number to `'0'` looks odd, and in the intro you said you were using `is not null`, which is confusing. Perhaps showing the table definitions and the actual output of the inner query, with and without the outer join (is that comparing the right fields, `g` to `f`?) might shed some light. At the moment I don't think it's quote clear what you're doing and seeing.

Comment: Please don't use the deprecated implicit join operator `(+)` any more. Use a explicit join with `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Your example [still gives 1 for all three `digitado` columns for `8220568059`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/02305/1), so I really don't understand what issue you have. What is the problem with those results - are you saying you get a zero for the first `digitado` when you run exactly the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that is the problem. The first case returns 0. The oracle version that I am using is 10.2.0.3. The other two colums, digitado2 and digitado3 return 1 just the way it should be. But the column digitado returns 0 and I can not undestand why. The same example has been run with SQLPLUS, TOAD, SQLMANAGER and the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should almost never use the comparison operators with `VARCHAR2`, it is almost never useful (except if you are writing a sorting algorithm). In your case especially, it doesn't do what you expect.

When you compare VARCHAR2s, the result will depend upon [character ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements002.htm#sthref311) (for instance `'2'` is "greater" than `'10'` because `2` comes after `1` in the character table).

Consider:

```
SQL> select * from dual where '8220568059' > '0';

DUMMY
-----
X

SQL> select * from dual where '    8220568059' > '0';

DUMMY
-----
```

Always use the right datatype for the right task. There is almost always only one datatype that will work correctly. You should always use `NUMBER` and **explicit** datatype conversion when working with numbers:

```
SQL> select * from dual where to_number('8220568059') > 0;

DUMMY
-----
X
```

Also if you just want to know if a value is NULL, please use the `IS NOT NULL` operator:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS (
  2  SELECT '8220568059' num_documento_encabezado,
  3         2 origen_planilla FROM dual UNION ALL
  4  SELECT '', 2 FROM dual UNION ALL
  5  SELECT '', 1 FROM dual)
  6  SELECT x.origen_planilla,
  7         x.num_documento_encabezado,
  8         CASE
  9            WHEN x.num_documento_encabezado IS NOT NULL
 10             AND x.origen_planilla = 2 THEN
 11             1
 12            ELSE
 13             0
 14         END digitado
 15    FROM DATA x;

ORIGEN_PLANILLA NUM_DOCUMENTO_ENCABEZADO   DIGITADO
--------------- ------------------------ ----------
              2 8220568059                        1
              2                                   0
              1                                   0
```

Comment: Well give us the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements so that we can reproduce and we won't have to guess =)

Comment: I have alredy shared the create and insert statements on the first post, it reproduces exactly the same error, I have also included some exampled that work and the one that doesn't.

Comment: Well I ran your script in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0fcba/2) and the 3 expressions return the same result: `CASE` is working fine with `AND`. Also I added your first expression (with `> '0'`) and it gives the same expected result. What version are you running?

Comment: I am running it with TOAD 11.5.1.2 oracle version 10.2.0.3, the problem is still there. I have also run the query with sqlplus and the result is the same, the first case doesn't work.

Comment: I can reproduce your finding on 9ir2. I don't know why it behaves like this, I can only guess that the expression is incorrectly merged into the inner query (GROUP BY) in conjunction with the outer join.

Comment: Might it be an oracle's problem? I guess it was alredy fixed in the newest versions of the engine. Howerver it is quite intriguing and makes you distrust about every operation like this one on previous versions to 11g. I have also discovered this, try filtering the query by adding the where clause after )x something like where x.num_documento_encabezado  is not null, it works in the where clause but not in the select section.

Comment: I've finally nailed it I think. It comes from a bad rewriting by the optimizer. The optimizer merges the inner query with the outer query incorrectly. If I add the hint `/+ NO_MERGE */` to the inner query I get correct results on 9.2.0.7.0. This seems to be a bug that has been fixed in 11i. I think it is a very rare occurrence (it needs GROUP BY+OUTER JOIN+CASE). Still I agree it is worrying.

Comment: Tested on 10.0.2.3 with the hint /*+ NO_MERGE */ worked perfectly.